# Java - Print 5 prime numbers in a row

Tags: java

My project is to print prime numbers between 0 and 100, but also display 5 of the prime numbers per row.

```
//Print first 100 Prime numbers.
        
for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
              
    int counter=0;    
        
    for(num =i; num>=1; num--) {
        if(i % num == 0) {
            counter = counter + 1;
        }
    }

    if (counter == 2) {
        //Display the output of 5 numbers per row.
        System.out.print(" " + i);
        if(i % 5 == 1) {
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
        //Prime number is assigned to the empty string class variable.
        displayPrimes = displayPrimes + i + " ";
    }
}
```

Output of prime numbers works fine, Im just struggling to get them assign to 5 values per row.

The current output looks like this:

> The 0-100 Prime numbers are:
>
> 2 3 5 7 11
>
> 13 17 19 23 29 31
>
> 37 41
>
> 43 47 53 59 61
>
> 67 71
>
> 73 79 83 89 97

This is the code that is meant to adapt 5 values per row.

```
//Display the output of 5 numbers per row.
          System.out.print(" " + i);
          if(i % 5 == 1) {
              System.out.print("\n");
          }
```

Comment: Is `i` the prime number? Then why would `i % 5 == 1` create 5 per row?

Comment: you need an extra counter variable to count the outputted values.

Comment: Load them all into an array. Then read the array five at a time, catch `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`, and print the rest.

Comment: It seems to me that he is a beginner in java, so I don't think he knows what arrays and exceptions are yet @ifly6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add one more int variable to count how many prime numbers have been printed for each row. When it prints 5 numbers in a row, it goes to the next line and then resets the counter(sets the variable to 0). Like this:

```
int count =0;
for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {

        int counter=0;    

        for( num =i; num>=1; num--)
        {
        if(i % num == 0)
    {
        counter = counter + 1;
            }
        }
        if (counter == 2)
        {
            //Display the output of 5 numbers per row.
          System.out.print(" " + i);
          count++;
          if(count == 5) {
              System.out.print("\n");
              count = 0;
          }
     //Prime number is assigned to the empty string class variable.
     displayPrimes = displayPrimes + i + " ";
        }
   }
```

Comment: Include why you made the changes you made.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `i` again, you need to use a new variable (I used `currentPrime`).
Because `i` is your prime number itself, not the index of the prime.

Also you need to add change `i = 1` to `int i = 1` in the for loops otherwise the code wont compile.

```
    int currentPrime = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {

        int counter=0;

        for(int num =i; num>=1; num--)
        {
            if(i % num == 0)
            {
                counter = counter + 1;
            }
        }
        if (counter == 2)
        {
            //Display the output of 5 numbers per row.
            System.out.print(" " + i);
            currentPrime++;

            if(currentPrime % 5 == 1)
            {
                System.out.print("\n");
            }
            //Prime number is assigned to the empty string class variable.
            displayPrimes = displayPrimes + i + " ";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

By checking

```
if (i % 5 == 1)
```

You are checking if the remainder after dividing i by five is 1. Since i is your prime number, this just means that a new line will print every time your prime number is 1 more than a multiple of 5 (hence why it gave you a new line after 11, 31, 41, etc).

What you need to do is set up a separate counter variable that keeps track of how many primes you have printed on that line. You can increment this variable every time you print a new prime, then print a new line and reset the prime counting variable after it reaches 5.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code implementation for instructions mentioned by User: 707090

```
public class PrimeNumberInRange {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    printPrimeNumbersInRange(2, 1000);
}

// returns true/ false
public static boolean isPrime(int n) {

    if (n < 2) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 2; i <= n / 2; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

// returns the list of number between min and max...
public static void printPrimeNumbersInRange(int min, int max) {

    if (min < 2 || max < 2) {
        System.out.println("Invalid range, should start with at least 2");
    } else {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
            
            if (isPrime(i)) {
                    System.out.print(i+" ");
                    count++;
                    
                 if (count % 10 == 0 ) {
                     System.out.println();
                 }

                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```